# android set interface with fragment and activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

i try to set and interface between fragment and activity first this the interface in my activity

```
private PLRListener KListener;

public interface  PLRListener{
    void updateProgress(long e, long z);
    void pause();
    void play(long e, long z);    
}
```

and i have viewPager with `FragmentPagerAdapter` now i set the listener on fragment

```
public class myfragment extends Fragment   implements MainActivity.PLRListener {

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setListener(this);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
         throw new ClassCastException("www");
    }
}

@Override
public void pause() {
   //change background on fragment
}

@Override
public void play(long e, long z) {
   //change text on fragment
}
```

}

now its work but work where on the next fragment not on the visible fragment 
so its on callback function change the background and text of layout  of the visible fragment

ex: i have three fragment and i start the application

fragment1  fragment2 fragment2

when iam on fragment2 and the callback function run its update on fragment3 when its on fragment1 and i run callback function its update fragment2

Comment: Yes Obviously it will do this! As you are setting listener everytime on attach in MainActivity.  can you post main activity code too

Answer (score 0):

If you work with `FragmentPagerAdapter` you have to consider that this class will load more than one fragment because of `OffscreenPageLimit` which default value is 1 and can't be lower than 1. You are setting the listener everytime `onAttach()` of fragment is called. `((MainActivity)getActivity()).setListener(this);`

Comment: Post your `MainActivity` code and we try to help ;)